# UIViewController and NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I create and launch a `NSURLConnection` in `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`. And `UIViewController` is set as a delegate for the `NSURLConnection`.

What will happen if `UIViewController` destroys (deallocates) before `NSURLConnection` has finished its work? It will try to call a delegate, I guess, and the app will crash.

Previously (before using ARC), I used to remember `NSURLConnection` by a strong reference and `cancel` it in `UIViewController`'s `dealloc` method.

Should I do something similar when using ARC. And if not, why?

Comment: When in doubt, conduct an experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why *wouldn't* you do the same thing when using ARC? If this was important to do before ARC, it is important to do after ARC. Memory management is memory management. The danger of a message being sent to a delegate that no longer exists is exactly the same. It's *all* the same, ARC or no ARC — except that under ARC, `retain` and `release` are being called for you.

Comment: By the way, consider switching to NSURLSession. It's way better. NSURLConnection is not deprecated yet, but it's on the way out.

Comment: See also the warning at the end of this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_retain_cycles_and_weak_references _You_ are using ARC, but _Cocoa_ mostly does not; delegate references are not ARC-weak, so Cocoa won't magically know if a delegate has been destroyed, and will still attempt to send a message to a nonexistent delegate, just as it would have done before ARC, because Cocoa itself _is_ before ARC.

Answer (score 1):

NSURLConnection must be storing some internal reference of connection object that why it wont be crashing. Personally i have been keeping strong reference as we don't know how actually internally sdk save these references and this behavior may also change with sdk.

You can avoid crashing when viewcontroller dealloc before connection object by setting delegate method to nil and calling cancel method on the instance